# How to assign template tag-value in loop?

Tags: django, templates

I have an HTML snippet which I like to re-use many times on a page.
For instance

```
<div id="custom">
    <p>{{ object_name }}</p>
    <p>{{ object_value }}</p>
    <p>Static text</p>
</div>
```

How can I include this snippet on a page/template, where the values of the template tags or assigned dynamically?

Currently I work with this solution:

```
<div class="custom">
    <p>{{ object_name_one }}</p>
    <p>{{ object_value_one }}</p>
    <p>Static text</p>
</div>
<div class="custom">
    <p>{{ object_name_two }}</p>
    <p>{{ object_value_two }}</p>
    <p>Static text</p>
</div>
<div class="custom">
    <p>{{ object_name_three }}</p>
    <p>{{ object_value_three }}</p>
    <p>Static text</p>
</div>
```

With a dictionary containing the respective values I pass in the `view` of this app. Instead of a list of objects containing the values, I assigned all values, for instance

```
{ ..., object_name_three = l[2].name, ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for item in dir %}
    <div class="hi">
        {{ item.one }}
        {{ item.two }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

and in your context:

```
context = {'dir':[{'one':'uno', 'two':'no'}, {'one':'uo', 'two':'sino'}]}
```

tell me if that works or I misunderstood